# solution for the graphic photovoltaik

Tags: javascript, gnuplot, jqplot

I am looking for a solution for the graphic.
The data come from a photovoltaic system
Orange = power relation, yellow = power captive, blue = power generated, green = power delivered
Is this possible with JQPlot? or gnuplot?

see: [graphic example](https://picasaweb.google.com/hartmut.weinmar/Sun?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCPfPq5vP4qWjFQ&feat=directlink)

Hartmut

Comment: The link should work now
   Hartmut

Answer (score 0):

With gnuplot you have the `filledcurve` option with which it should be possible to achieve what you are after.

Check out the documentation on filledcurves [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-24800043.59.8.6) and a tutorial [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/fillcrvs.html).